# Why is there no option to only send an azurepipeline alert in Slack if the release is succesful?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up alerts in slack using `/azpipeline susbscribe [url]`and my release pipeline is connected. I'm seeing this notification for my pipeline however I don't know how to modify the environment status.

```
For stage: any, environment status: any
```

How can I ensure that a notification is only sent when the release pipeline is succesful. I want it to ignore failing builds. I tried to redo the `azpipelines subscribe` command however it says the channel is already subscribed for notifications from that pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the existing notification to the subscription, then re-add the specific notification and modify the parameters which are required. For example here: by selecting remove then re-adding the subscription you can modify the notification further, it must be removed first.

[image]